# How to find optimal block size and LWORK in LAPACK

Tags: fortran, lapack

I am trying to find inverse and eigenfunctions of nxn Hermitian matrices using Fortran with lapack.

How do I choose the optimal values for parameters like `lda`, `lwork`, `liwork` and `lrwork`. I browse through some example and find these choices

```
integer,parameter::lda=nh
integer,parameter::lwork=2*nh+nh*nh
integer,parameter::liwork=3+5*nh
integer,parameter::lrwork=1 + 5*nh + 2*nh*nh
```

where `nh` is the dimension of the matrix. I also find another example with  `lwork=16*nh`. How can I determine the best choice? At this point, I am dealing with 500x500 Hermitian matrices (maximum).

I found [this documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node120.html) which suggests

> WORK
>
> (workspace) REAL array, dimension (LWORK)
>
> On exit, if INFO = 0, then WORK(1) returns the optimal LWORK.
>
> LWORK
>
> (input) INTEGER
>
> The dimension of the array WORK. LWORK ￼ max(1,N).
>
> For optimal performance LWORK ￼ N*NB, where NB is the optimal block size returned by ILAENV.

Is it possible to find out the optimal block size using `WORK` or `ILAENV` for a given matrix dimension?

I am using both gfortran and ifort with mkl.

---

**EDIT**

Based on the comment by  @percusse and [@kvantour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49411046/5762127) here is a sample code

```
character,parameter::jobz="v",uplo="u"
integer, parameter::nh=15
complex*16::m(nh,nh),m1(nh,nh)

integer,parameter::lda=nh
integer::ipiv(nh),info

complex*16::work(1)
real*8::rwork(1), w(nh)
integer::iwork(1)
real*8::x1(nh,nh),x2(nh,nh)

call random_seed()
call random_number(x1)
call random_number(x2)

m=cmplx(x1,x2)
m1=conjg(m)
m1=transpose(m1)
m=(m+m1)/2.0

call zheevd(jobz,uplo,nh,m,lda,w,work,-1,rwork,-1,iwork, -1,info)

print*,"info : ", info
print*,"lwork: ", int(work(1))   , 2*nh+nh*nh
print*,"lrwork:", int(rwork(1))  , 1 + 5*nh + 2*nh*nh
print*,"liwork:", int(iwork(1))  , 3+5*nh

end
```

> info :           0
>
> lwork:         255         255
>
> lrwork:        526         526
>
> liwork:         78          78

Comment: You first call the function with `LWORK=-1` and get the optimal block size. Then you call the function again with those returned values

Comment: There are _very_ few cases where one would actually want to compute the inverse of a 500x500 matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are implying with *"Is it possible to find out the optimal block size using `WORK` or `ILAENV` for a particular machine architecture?"*. You can however find the optimal values for a particular problem.

Eg. If you want to find the eigenvalues of a complex Hermitian matrix, using `cheev`, you can ask the routine to return you the value :

```
subroutine CHEEV( JOBZ, UPLO, N, A, LDA, W, WORK, LWORK, RWORK, INFO )
  character                , intent(in)    :: JOBZ
  character                , intent(in)    :: UPLO
  integer                  , intent(in)    ::  N
  complex, dimension(lda,*), intent(inout) :: A
  integer                  , intent(in)    :: LDA
  real   , dimension(*)    , intent(out)   :: W
  complex, dimension(*)    , intent(out)   :: WORK
  integer                  , intent(in)    :: LWORK
  real   , dimension(*)    , intent(out)   :: RWORK
  integer                  , intent(out)   :: INFO
```

Then the [documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/complex/cheev.f) clearly states (be advised, in the past this was easier to read):

> `WORK` is `COMPLEX` array, dimension `(MAX(1,LWORK))`
>             On exit, if `INFO = 0`, `WORK(1)` returns the optimal `LWORK`.
>
> `LWORK` is `INTEGER`
>             The length of the array `WORK`.  `LWORK >= max(1,2*N-1)`.
>             For optimal efficiency, `LWORK >= (NB+1)*N`,
>             where `NB` is the blocksize for `CHETRD` returned by `ILAENV`. If `LWORK = -1`, then a workspace query is assumed; the routine
>             only calculates the optimal size of the `WORK` array, returns
>             this value as the first entry of the `WORK` array, and no error
>             message related to `LWORK` is issued by `XERBLA`.

So all you need to do is

```
call cheev(jobz, uplo, n, a, lda, w, work, -1, rwork, info)
lwork=int(work(1))
dallocate(work)
allocate(work(lwork))
call cheev(jobz, uplo, n, a, lda, w, work, lwork, rwork, info)
```

Comment: Thanks, @kvantour. I got this impression that these numbers may change with the processor type and hardware. So I can run a test with `lwork=-1` this for a nxn random Hermitian matrix,  get all the other parameter (like `lwork`, `rwork` etc) and then use them for any nxn Hermitian matrix. Is it so?

Comment: @Sumit yes, the output will not depend on the content of `A`. But on the arguments that define the problem (`UPLO`, `JOBZ`, `LDA`, `N` in case of `cheev`)

Comment: I am using `zheevd`. I guess the rule is same and I have to find `iwork` from `liwork(1)` in addition.

Comment: thanks @kvantour. I get the correct value for `lwork` and `lrwork`, but  getting wrong result for `liwork`. I modified my question with a sample code.

Comment: @Sumit your arguments are incorrect. `work` is complex, `rwork` real, `iwork` integer ... Etc. Have a look at the link I've send. It clearly states the types of the arguments.

Comment: I see the actual problem now. I need to sleep.